# First Haskell IO program isn't working

Tags: haskell

Sorry, this is probably really dumb, but can someone explain me why this program doesn't compile? I get `Couldn't match expected type 'a1 -> String' with actual type 'IO String'`.

```
import System.Environment

main = do
  [first, last] <- getArgs
  firstnames <- lines . readFile "firstnames_male"
  lastnames <- lines . readFile "lastnames"
  print firstnames
```

Comment: It's not a dumb question, but this kind of compiler error (from the type-checker) is the most common type of error you'll encounter programming haskell so it might be worth taking the time to understand what this means (and how to read a type signature, if necessary) before moving on. You can search SO for "couldn't match expected type" for lots of answers that walk you through how to find and fix type errors.

Comment: @jberryman I'm going through a book pretty rigorously, eventually I'll learn about all this IO stuff, but right now I just want my program to work.

Comment: That's great, but the fact that there's `IO` in your type doesn't have much to do with your error, or how you'd go about isolating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do `lines . readFile "lastnames"`.

The `readFile` function returns an `IO String`, not a `String`.

You *can*, however, use the `fmap` function (or the `<$>` operator) to achieve this:

```
main = do
  [first, last] <- argArgs
  firstnames <- lines `fmap` readFile "firstnames_males"
  ...
```

This works because `IO` is a functor.

Comment: I'll learn what that all means when I get further into the book I'm reading, I guess, for now I'll just take your word for it!

Comment: What it means is that you can think of "readFile" as an IO action "wrapped around" a string. Wrappers like this are known as "functors". The "fmap" function lets you reach inside the functor wrapper and do keyhole surgery to the contents without actually taking the wrapper off.